# Best software/website to plot intervals

Tags: graphing-functions, math-software, interval-arithmetic

What is the best software if I want to plot an interval, say $[0,+\infty) \times[5,10]\subset\mathbb{R}^2$? Preferably freely available. Of course I could do this with Desmos, LaTeX, or even Excel - but all of them seem quite inconvenient. I know Mathematica is probably the best but unfortunately I don't have access to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will recommend GeoGebra Classic, it is FREE and joins graphing, geometry, 3D, spreadsheets, computer algebra and probability in one easy-to-use and powerful package.

Figure. In input field type this: $x >= 0 \quad  \&\& \quad 5 <= y <= 10$
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Also [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x+%3E%3D0%2C++5+%3C%3D+y+%3C%3D+10) : `x >=0,  5 <= y <= 10` gives this picture:

[image]